# Convert String to Data for use with NSJSONSerialization

Tags: swift

I have a String that looks something like this: (it's derived from a decoded data object that's slightly malformed that I fix and verify this output via the console)

```
{"home":{"breakfast":{"protein":"55","carbs":"55","fiber":"55"},"snack":{"water":"55","fiber":"55"},"nextSnack":{"water":"55","fiber":"55"}}}
```

I then want to convert that string to data for use with NSJSONSerialization, I do that like this:

```
let cleanStringData = cleanString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

The object I get back after doing this:

```
if let jsonObject = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(cleanStringData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject] {


    print(jsonObject)

}
```

Doesn't always have quotes encapsulating the keys and values. How would I go about fixing that? Your help is always appreciate,d thank you.

Comment: What *"Doesn't always have quotes encapsulating the keys and values"*? The `jsonObject`? Have you tried sending it to a server, what exactly is the output of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing to fix: it's due to how "print" interprets the object contents when it's typed AnyObject. Try accessing your dictionary values you'll see that the keys are actual strings, even if they're shown without double quotes.

```
let cleanString = "{\"home\":{\"breakfast\":{\"protein\":\"55\",\"carbs\":\"55\",\"fiber\":\"55\"},\"snack\":{\"water\":\"55\",\"fiber\":\"55\"},\"nextSnack\":{\"water\":\"55\",\"fiber\":\"55\"}}}"

let cleanStringData = cleanString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

do {
    if let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(cleanStringData!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] {
        if let home = jsonObject["home"] as? [String:AnyObject],
            let snack = home["snack"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                print(snack) // ["water": 55, "fiber": 55]
        }
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: well that's embarrassing lol - thank you. I had been in such a state of verification while I was decrypting the original data I mentioned that I kept using the console to verify what I was doing.