# Spotify Returns Invalid NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, spotify, nsjsonserialization

I am calling the Spotify API method to retrieve a user's saved tracks. While parsing the return data, I call

```
let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataFromNetwork, options: []) as! NSDictionary
```

When I print out the result I get:

```
{
href = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks?offset=0&limit=20";
items =     (
            {
        "added_at" = "2016-04-17T18:35:07Z";
        track =             {
            album =                 {
                "album_type" = album;
                "available_markets" =   
    ....
}
```

Some of the keys aren't strings. Therefore, when I try to navigate through the containers, it returns errors.

I first navigate to the list of tracks with:

```
let tracks = jsonObject["items"] as! [NSDictionary]
```

This code doesn't generate errors. However, when I  iterate through the array, I try to access the "name" key for the track:

```
let title = track["name"] as! String
```

This code crashes the program and when I look at the JSON:

```
name = <redacted>
```

There are no double quotes around neither the key nor the value.

Comment: you need to encode those strings

Comment: Which key aren't string? How did you affirm that?

Comment: can you tell me which key is not a proper string.

Comment: `Some of the keys aren't strings` Then it's not JSON. // But, actually, I think you're making the classic mistake: you're looking at the result of `print` or `NSLog`: in both cases, some keys/values will be printed without quotes. But they *are* Strings nonetheless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839233/convert-string-to-data-for-use-with-nsjsonserialization

Comment: Swift doesn't print a dictionary as JSON, it prints the dictionary as ASCII plist, which is an older, similar-looking but different way of encoding such data. You can't mix and match those. So not sure your assumption that some keys aren't strings is valid. I think you're being misled and your problem is something else, like Michael Dautermann's answer, maybe some entries just don't have certain keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is a little too absolute:

```
let title = track["name"] as! String
```

Change it to a "`if let`" statement:

```
if let title = track["name"] as? String
{
   // do something if it's a valid title
```